# Is it possible in multithreaded environment to use the singletons instance by only one thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I am using singleton classes, and I have more threads running. I want to achieve that while thread 1 is using a singleton instance, thread 2 is blocking, and after thread 1 finishes with the instance, the other thread can use it.

I use synchronized in `getInstance()`, but it only ensures that only one thread can *request* the instance at the same time. It does not ensure that only one thread can *work* with the instance at a time.

Comment: Sounds horribly inefficient. Is it not possible to make the singleton thread-safe?

Comment: Well, if you **want** that, you'll have to make the methods of the singleton synchronized. But I second @Kayaman : This will be a bottleneck!

Comment: It would help to know what the singleton is being used for.

Comment: as Kayaman and @Fildor say, this is like stoping the workers of an office to wait to the fotocopier to finish, it is VERY inefficient. Another example is, stopping al the cars of a road while one is crossing the bridge, a lot of people would be angry.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make the code *almost* safe using a callback:

```
class MySingleton {
    // no public getInstance() here

    public interface Callback {
        void doWithSingleton(MySingleton singleton);
    }

    public static synchronized void doWithSingleton (Callback cb) {
        cb.doWithSingleton(instance);
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
MySingleton.doWithSingleton(new Callback() {
    public void doWithSingleton(MySingleton singleton) {
        singleton.method1();
        singleton.method2();
    }
});
```

This way, the singleton knows when the user will stop working with the instance, and can release the lock (exit the synchronized block / method). Same pattern may be used to implement anything that needs some init and cleanup that user must not forget to perform.

That the user will only work with the singleton within the given method is "ensured" by singleton instance only being available as a local variable in the callback. Note that this is not completely safe as you can't prevent user from copying the instance into a global variable - but it takes quite some effort for the user to break it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
If i want to call the doWithSingleton(Callback cb) method, what argument should i pass? 
If i have more methods, i just have to do like here?
 public interface Callback {
        void doWithSingleton1(MySingleton singleton);
        void doWithSingleton2(MySingleton singleton);
    }

Comment: See updated answer. The point is to do the whole work (that needs to be done while other threads are blocked) within the one callback.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a weird requirement. Still you could have something like Singleton provider that gives *and takes back* the singleton we are talking about.

This could be achieved even with static methods:

```
class SN {

private static final SN instance = new SN(....) // your thingy
private static final Lock instanceLock = ... // the lock protecting your thingy

public static SN get() {
    lock.lock()
    return instance
}

public static void giveBack(SN instance) {
    if (null != instance) {
        lock.unlock()
    }
}

}
```

The invariant here is: `as long I have reference to SN object, I am keeping access to SN.instanceLock`.
Obviously you need to ensure that your user follows the typical get-finally-giveBack idiom.

But as others have suggested, best would be to avoid a need for such design and make the singleton thread safe.